# Error converting JSON response from backend to type with JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

Tags: c#, json, serialization

So I am having this weird problem with deserializing a response from my BackEnd, The request works fine and the BackEnd succesfully responds with a result.

This is the error I get:

```cs
'Error converting value "{"Succes":true,"AuthKey":"$2a$13..."}" to type 'FrontEnd.LoginUserResponse'. Path '', line 1, position 96.'
```

The code I am using to make the HTTP call and deserialize the string:

```
public async Task<bool> loginUser(LoginUserData login)
        {
            HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(login), Encoding.UTF8);
            httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://ip/webBackEnd/api/user/login", httpContent);
            string response2 = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            LoginUserResponse response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginUserResponse>(response2);
            if (response.Succes)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else { return false; }
        }
```

I tried making a response2 to check the value and I have noticed it does something weird with 3 backslashes. This might be the reason why this is occuring.

This is response2 that visual studio shows when I click the magnifying glass:

```cs
"{\"Succes\":true,\"AuthKey\":\"$2a$11$tQCw4zGGd2J2fXAxAN68Ruu3xheTuMKq4EHbeLtc9DAa2rgzJe8bS\"}"
```

When I hover on visual studio:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5fAn.jpg

This is the Class that it is converting to

```cs
    public class LoginUserResponse
    {
        [JsonProperty("succes")]
        public bool succes { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("authkey")]
        public string authkey { get; set; }
    }
```

The Backend code:

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("login")]
        public string Login([FromBody]LogInData logInData)
        {
            IReadUser.LogInRequest request = new IReadUser.LogInRequest(logInData);
            IReadUser.LogInResponse backResponse = readUser.logIn(request);

            LogInResponse response = new LogInResponse();

            response.succes = backResponse.Succes;
            response.authkey = backResponse.AuthKey;

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
        }
```

**EDIT** // SOLUTION

Ok so, the front-end was fine, it was my backend code sending a double serialised string. I used

```cs
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
```

When I also could have used

```cs
return response;
```

So if you every get an error like this, it's probably the backend doubling up on the serialization.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: JSON is case-sensitive and the `JsonProperty` attributes have the *wrong* case. The property names are fine.

Comment: I tried changing it already multiple times, but still no succes. The response I get from backend is lowercase

Comment: What you posted is *not* lowercase. It's `{"Succes":true,"AuthKey":"$2a$13..."}`. Remove the `JsonProperty` attributes, or post the backend code. The error has nothing to do with the code you posted or the form of the URL

Comment: @JasperB Could you please post response2 sample json string. Because the one which you pasted here is working fine as shown here in dotnet fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/A0edym. I am thinking AuthKey might be having some characters which might be causing the issue. In order to debug further, comment out authkey property and try to deserialize the response. If it works, then it must be issue with authkey value

Comment: @sam I tried posting a plain string in the deserialize, but this worked fine, so I guess it has something to do in how Visual studio reads the string from the api? Edited that to the post btw

Comment: @JasperB: The json response that you posted also working fine: https://dotnetfiddle.net/a2GcDo. In the post, you mentioned that issue with 3 backslashes. But I don't see three backslashes in the sample response that you pasted.

Comment: @sam Yea indeed, I was trying that myself, thats really weird. https://imgur.com/a/jUyLz6d This is what I get when I hover over it, the string in the post is what I get with the maginfying glass. I don't understand how it works in the fiddle

Comment: According to your screenshot, it looks as if your backend response was invalid json. I'd double check that the response is not quoted. Wrong `"{\"prop\": 1}"`correct: `{"prop": 1}` - that's how your response body should look like.

Comment: Yeah I'll check that when I'm home!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things:
1. you should await `responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`:

```
public async Task<bool> loginUser(LoginUserData login)
{
    var httpContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(login), Encoding.UTF8);
    httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    var responseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://ip/webBackEnd/api/user/login", httpContent);
    var response2 = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginUserResponse>(response2);

    return response.Succes
}
```

And 2. Based on your image it looks like the response from your backing service is being serialized twice.

1:

```
"{\"Succes\":true,\"AuthKey\":\"$2a$11$tQCw4zGGd2J2fXAxAN68Ruu3xheTuMKq4EHbeLtc9DAa2rgzJe8bS\"}"
```

2:

```
"\"{\\\"Succes\\\":true,\\\"AuthKey\\\":\\\"$2a$11$tQCw4zGGd2J2fXAxAN68Ruu3xheTuMKq4EHbeLtc9DAa2rgzJe8bS\\\"}\""
```

now to deserialize you have to do it twice

```
var s = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(response2);            
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginUserResponse>(s);
```

Probably best to fix the service if that's actually what is happening

Comment: This is the code from the backend: https://imgur.com/a/FUJHA2J
The weird thing is that if I use https://reqbin.com/ to make the calls, that site can perfectly map it to JSON

Comment: I was able to Serialize the input twice to make it work, but It's weird because I don't know how I could send it diffrently from backend

Comment: Your service is serializing it twice. Drop the JsonConvet.... and return the type, not a string.

Comment: No problem, glad to help